# Performing specific action when user clicks any HTML element

Tags: html, css

I am creating navigation buttons that will drop down sub-menu when clicked, using checkbox input. Whenever user clicks the label input is checked and menu drop's down, when clicking the label again, it is being collapsed back.

But now i need to perform specific action, i am trying to make dropdown menu collapse when any HTML element is clicked, so user doesn't need to click the specific element to collapse menu.

HTML & CSS code specifically for dropdown menu:

```
<ul class="down-bar" style="list-style:hidden">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" value="drop" id="drop-1" class="dropper">
        <li><label class="down-nav" id="down-nav-1" for="drop-1" style="text-decoration:none">Click <b class="caret"> &#9660;</b></label></li>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#">Link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 0em;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  float: left;
  display: none;
  top: 0%;
  margin-top: 2.2%;
  width: 8%;
  min-width: 50px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 2);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 99;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 0%;
}
.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color: #C90205;
}
.dropper {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.dropper:checked ~ .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
}
.dropper:checked ~ li #down-nav-1 {
  border: solid 3px gray;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

---

I have tried few examples, such as using full width anchor tag, but then main menu would disappear, i was going to use `:active` tag to change menu's display back to `None`. see the [full code](https://jsfiddle.net/bqj6myea/embedded/result/). ( remove comment tags for full width example ).

So in the conclusion, how could i achieve this without making other elements disappear, do i have some mistake in code? is first example good solution? If so, how? How could i make menu collapse back when user clicks any HTML element? Can this be achieved without use of Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with javascript solution you can use this example:

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (! ($('#down-nav-1').is(e.toElement) || $('#drop-1').is(e.toElement))) {
    $('.dropper').prop('checked', false)
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 0em;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  float: left;
  display: none;
  top: 0%;
  margin-top: 2.2%;
  width: 8%;
  min-width: 50px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 2);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 99;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 0%;
}
.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color: #C90205;
}
.dropper {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.dropper:checked ~ .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
}
.dropper:checked ~ li #down-nav-1 {
  border: solid 3px gray;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="down-bar" style="list-style:hidden">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" value="drop" id="drop-1" class="dropper">
        <li><label class="down-nav" id="down-nav-1" for="drop-1" style="text-decoration:none">Click <b class="caret"> &#9660;</b></label></li>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#">Link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution,  is it impossible with only use of HTML / CSS?

Comment: With the current structure I'm not sure if there is.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work ( There is no change) , i think it's because i am importing static file wrong, i use django framework for my website, and this is what i added to code: `<script src="{% static 'Home/Home.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` am i doing something wrong? sorry, i have never used javascript.

Comment: If you put the code inside `/Home/Home.js` then the file `jquery.min.js` should appear before.

Comment: You are welcome :) Will appreciate also a voteup on the answer if you didn't vote yet!